# Is there any way to resize the UIPickerView so that I can see completely it in center of my application?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

Hello
I am trying to resize the UIPickerView as below dimension are given, but it is not working at all as I want it to be visible. Here datePicker is UIPickerView which is declared properly and synthesized too, now what should I do?

```
datePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 150)];
datePicker.delegate = self;
datePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
```

If you are not getting what exactly I mean, you can ask me again,,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   CGAffineTransform s0 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x,y);
        myPickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(s0, t1);
```

You can use 0.5 as scalefactor to resize the pickerview to 50%, and change x and y to appropriate values to make pickerview to appear in desired position. 
Note: import QuartzCore framework.

Answer (score 1):

use this,

```
CGRect pickerFrame=self.datePicker.frame;

    //for change height and width
    pickerFrame.size.width=20;
    pickerFrame.size.height=40;

    //for change in x and y coordinate

    pickerFrame.origin.y -=20;
    pickerFrame.origin.x -=20;

    self.datePicker.frame=pickerFrame;
```

use this code according to you.

Comment: THis is better and easy way what I did                                                                                                                               "picker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6);"

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust the width of a picker but not height. For height, you can overlay images(or anything) over your picker so that it looks small. Hope it helps.

Comment: I also need help for the width, I want to make width smaller so that I should not touch the border of my iphone,

Comment: I suggest that you hook it up in the interface builder and adjust it. its pretty easy

Comment: I don't want to use IB for my app, so can u tell me any method, or coding manually, I tried CGRectMake, but is not working so pretty as I want