# at run-time(objective-c), how do you place a UIPickerView in a resized UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uipickerview

I am seeing that the way to shrink the width of the UIPickerView is to put it in a resized UIView.  But the examples are at design time.  At run-time(objective-c), how do you place a UIPickerView in a resized UIView, as I am doing this to 4 of them to be side by side ?

thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do a bit more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use picker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.7, 0.6); something like this and try...
This will reduce the width as well height ...
Try changing the values in the above scale and try it..
and also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941808/is-there-any-way-to-resize-the-uipickerview-so-that-i-can-see-completely-it-in-ce)