# UIDatePicker in count down timer mode not supporting resizing?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a `UIDatePicker` in count down timer mode . `UIDatePicker` by default is not supporting auto resizing. So I manually set the frame to resize for the landscape orientation

```
- (void) resizeDatePicker: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
 {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) 
      {
    self.timePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 216);
      }
    else 
     {
    self.timePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 480, 162);
     }
  }
```

Its works in all other modes except for count down timer. In count down mode it's not appearing clearly.

[image: UIDatePicker in landscape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem.. Iam posting my answer here.. may help others. In count down timer mode you cannot  resize the frame directly. So I added the date picker as subview of a view then apply **CGAffineTransformMakeScale** to the view. Then I set the frame to appropriate position also.

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) 
{

    self.pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    self.pickerView.frame =CGRectMake(0,40, 320, 216);

}
else 
{

    self.pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.65, 0.65);
    self.pickerView.frame =CGRectMake(0,40, 480, 140);

}
```

It will reduce the size of the picker by 65%. PickerView is the view contains the picker.
The following question help me to solve this problem

1. [How to change UIPickerView height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573979/how-to-change-uipickerview-height)
2. [Can We resize the UIDatePicker View in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173485/can-we-resize-the-uidatepicker-view-in-iphone)
3. [Is there any way to resize the UIPickerView so that I can see completely it in center of my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941808/is-there-any-way-to-resize-the-uipickerview-so-that-i-can-see-completely-it-in-c)