# UIDatePicker gets black in landscape on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, datepicker, landscape

I have UIDatePicker that in potrait mode lokes like this

[image: Picker in potrait]

And when spawn it or rotate to landscape it suddelny gets black like this

[image: Picker in landscape]

This problem occurs both if i first spawned the picker in landscape and when i rotate it to landscape. All in all as soon as the phone is in landscape the picker gets black. Picker is created as follows in viewDidAppear.

```
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 216)];
[picker addTarget:self action:@selector(change:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];  
[picker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer];
[picker setMinuteInterval:5];
[self.view addSubview:picker];
```

The picker still works in landscape but the ugly black background for everything is not so pleasing for the eye. Any ideas of what the problem can be?

Comment: you  need to set frame in iphone landscape mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced the same issue while trying to reset the frame of the date picker(countdown mode). Actually it wont support the frame resize. You can check the solution that i found here

[UIDatePicker in count down timer mode not supporting resizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580565/uidatepicker-in-count-down-timer-mode-not-supporting-resizing)